# Create custom toolbar for ios in xamarin visual studio 17

Tags: xamarin.forms

I want to create a custom toolbar with app name and his icon this toolbar should be included in all Page of the applications. This toolbar should be for ios because in all others examples which i haave seen they are using Main.storyboard which iss not in visual studio 17. Thanks

Comment: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/toolbar-icon-in-xamarin-cross-platform-with-example/

Comment: https://montemagno.com/xamarin-forms-icons-in-navigation-toolbar/

Comment: Have you solved it? If other problems ,I will update my answer.Thanks in advance for marking it.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to create a custom toolbar with app name and his icon this toolbar

You can refer to [this official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.toolbaritem?view=xamarin-forms) to know more about ToolBarItem in Xamarin Forms.

Code as follow in **Xaml**:

```
<ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
    <ToolbarItem Name="MenuItem1" Icon="icon.png" Priority="0" Order="Primary"  />
</ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
```

Or in **ContentPage** :

```
 new ToolbarItem () { Icon = "icon.png" }
```

And this app name can be setted in ContentPage with **Title** property as follow:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:App3"
             xmlns:autocomplete="clr-namespace:Syncfusion.SfAutoComplete.XForms;assembly=Syncfusion.SfAutoComplete.XForms"
             x:Class="App3.MainPage"
             Title="AppNameTitle">
```

Here is a good [article](https://xamarinhelp.com/xamarin-forms-toolbar/) for reference.